# Can I use the mosfet for 5 volt to 3.3 volt logic converter

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, fet

I have a BSS138 circuit below the schematic

I want to Convert 5 volt to 3.3 volt logic level shifter that using this BSS138.

SCHEMATİC
[image]

Now. I am trying the circuit on the board, but does not work. Can you help me?

Comment: The circuit you are trying to make is a bidirectional level shifter for open collector signals. But you didn't do it right. And it looks like you don't need a bidirectional level shifter. You could actually just use a resistor divider to convert 5V to 3.3.

Comment: Resistor divider will work but it is limited by frequency. For frequencies up to the 10khz range it is okay.

Comment: I need really fast frequency and with a mosfet.

Comment: The resistor divider frequency response can be improved by adding a capacitor in parallel with the high-side resistor. You can get away with fairly large resistors by doing this.

Comment: I really need this for . Because it is does not work on the board

Answer (score 2):

Google MOSFET level shifter. You need to pullup to +5 to get 5V at the output.

edit: [Here is the first hit](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/mosfet-voltage-level-converter):

[image]

It should be obvious that the way you have the MOSFET won't work (just look at the substrate diode- it will conduct with +5 on the left side).

The turn on voltage of the BSS138 is a bit on the marginal side, but probably good enough for your purposes.

Comment: I can not try this BSS138 because my mosfets far a way from me  nowadays. I searched it on google but Always show me 3.3 volt to 5 volt. Not 5 volt to 3.3 volt

Comment: This is a bidirectional converter, however it is not fast. For fast (10ns) you should use a tiny level translator chip, not this MOSFET.

Comment: Dear Spehro, Thanks you answer. My maximum frequence fast 10us.İt is good for me

Comment: 10us with 10K pullup and 100pf load including 10-15pF for the transistor, the time constant will be 1us so it will probably work okay.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this video. [Level shift solutions](https://youtu.be/t-yuYasIKtY)

Is shows several quick solutions. There are dedicated ics that work better with higher frequencies

Comment: The OP is trying to convert a 5V signal to a 3.3V signal. Does not seem to be asking for 5V from a 3.3V supply as far as I can see.

Comment: Oh rigth, sorry. The video explains both anyway.

Comment: Fixed schematics on the question message. Thank you.