# Controlling servo with MOSFET

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, servo, nodemcu

I'm trying to understand how to drive a servo that needs 5 V power with a 3.3 V output microcontroller. If I have a 3.3 V PWM signal and a 5 V power source, is there a way that I can use a single N-Channel MOSFET to control the servo's motion?

Comment: you just need a voltage level converter from 3.3V to 5V, the MOSFET can be used, but there's no need to use any power components.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/275468/can-i-use-the-mosfet-for-5-volt-to-3-3-volt-logic-converter https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/622/bi-directional-step-up-and-step-down-3-3v-5-etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use the mosfet for 5 volt to 3.3 volt logic converter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/275468/can-i-use-the-mosfet-for-5-volt-to-3-3-volt-logic-converter)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just connect it directly. See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/118390/drive-a-4-8v-servo-signal-line-using-3-3v) comment by @BruceAbbott:

> all modern rc receivers output 3.0~3.3V pulses, so any servo sold
> today has to work at this voltage. – Bruce Abbott